# css position an element at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, positioning

I need some tips about the best way to position one or more image at the bottom of the page or a container div. If possible css only.

The only way I can accomplish that is using jquery :(

Answer (score 26):

Try `position: fixed`. That will position any block element (div, image) at a fixed location with respect to the page. The element will stay there when you scroll (except on tablet/mobile devices). For example:

```
div#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

  /* And if you want the div to be full-width: */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I said bottom of the page, I was talking about bottom of the document, and not bottom of the window browser.  When I load the page the image isn't visible, but when I scroll down to the end I can see it. Did U understand??

Comment: You're probably looking for `position: absolute` then.

Comment: Worked fine for me but div in front of # is extraneous.  I'm using it in Blazor to put a logo at bottom of my NavMenu.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `position: absolute` for it. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R2V4U/

Answer (score 1):

`Position: 'absolute'` is the answer, however you might want to set your body or a a div container for `position: 'relative'` to give a point of reference to the image.

I tried using this for footer at the bottom of a document and it worked only when I set my body for `position: 'relative'`. Having said that, it might not be the best practice to set body like this, so it is best to use a container with relative position for your whole page inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same kind of problem and everything found on the web was either too complicated, or not not functionnal in some cases. The easiest way I found is like this :

```
<html>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;min-height:95%;">Content</div>
<div style="height:5%;position: relative;bottom:0px;">Footer</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Obviously you can extract the css in stylesheet and add "class" or "ID" to the divs.

Answer (score -1):

```
#mydivid{
     position : fixed;
     bottom : 0;
}
```

would do the job.

Comment: When I said bottom of the page, I was talking about bottom of the document, and not bottom of the window browser.  When I load the page the image isn't visible, but when I scroll down to the end I can see it. Did U understand??

Comment: Yep, I got that... So why don't you place the element that you whant to be the last, on the lats position in html structure ?

Comment: I don't know what the OP is trying to do, but personally, I'm currently trying to get an apparently-mandatory widget in Blogger moved to a better location, for a client. There are cases where you can't do the Right Thing, sadly.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is pretty old but I think my answer is the correct one if you don't want element to display over other elements when changing size of window.
So to accomplish this I created div container inside which I stored element I want to display at the bottom of the page, then I used flexbox to justify it.
https://jsfiddle.net/08xrab3w/9/

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#bottom-of-page-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#bottom-of-page {
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
   height: 60px;
}
```

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="bottom-of-page-container">
    <div id="bottom-of-page"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```